# How to create your own wallet

Tags: bitcoin, ethereum, mining

I am a newbie to cryptocurrency. I want to create my own wallet (preferably using node js), so can someone please help me in the process. Also, how mining will work in the same case?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You would be embarking on a great adventure doing so, and I can think of some resources that you may also find useful along the way :

- ["Mastering bitcoin"](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802) A great primer on bitcoin, totally worth the read:  (free to read online)
- [The bitcoin core repository](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin)
- [Ethereum Go wallet implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)
- [How to build a tiny blockchain in python](https://medium.com/crypto-currently/lets-build-the-tiniest-blockchain-e70965a248b) (wallet implementation in second part of the tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for replying..can u pls tell that if suppose i create a wallet address on one platform, can i use it for trnasactions on another wallet platform?

Comment: Hum, I thought you were interested in the inner working of a wallet. The bets place to start if you want to play with a crypto is to go on their website and to download their wallet. Follow the documentation there, and you should be good. Still, I deeply recommend you to read the "Mastering bitcoin" book first, as it will provide you with sufficient knowledge to start.